# Are pictures in comments possible?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I added a comment to a question, and instead of an image popping up, this did:

`![http://i.imgur.com/DXSVh.png][1]`

Comment: here it won't even show it in the question.  I put "![this][1] [1]: i.imgur.com/DXSVh.png" in the quotations, and the picture didn't show up.

Comment: you left out the `http://` and used the wrong domain. At any rate, no, you cannot embed images in comments. Can you provide a link to the question this problem occurred on?

Comment: This question.  Thanks.

Comment: _What_ question? I don't see any link to a question?

Comment: Do not change the intention of your answered question, you should create a new question. ([Your edit](http://meta.superuser.com/revisions/3083/3))

Comment: Do you have a reason they need to show up?

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't post images in comments. You can, however, link to images as if they were a normal URL. Just use the normal `[link text](url)` syntax.

Comments are meant to be lightweight, and primarily just text. Images in comments would be extremely ineffective given the potential image size that would make the comments thread overly long, so for that reason keeping them linked as text would be functionally more useful.

Comment: But SE doesn't host the pictures (confirmable by right clicking on the image, and selecting "copy image URL").  If there was an arrow that users could click to display the picture within the comment...

Comment: @wizlog You can upload an image onto an answer, and just copy the URL from the answer rather than actually posting that answer. That way, you'll have it uploaded to our system properly.

Comment: But that's not what I'm looking to do! I'm looking to show the picture in the comment, not just a link to it.

Comment: @wizlog And I noted, that's not possible in the current system, and it is unlikely to be implemented due to the purpose of comments to being lightweight text. Adding images is adding both a lot of physical size to comments, and a lot of often extraneous functionality. If you need the image shown straight up, it may be wiser to simply edit that into your post than to put it in a comment.

Comment: @wizlog: A comment is a remark expressing an opinion or reaction on the question or answer. There is no point in actually showing a picture in the comment, people can just click on [a link to the image](http://i.imgur.com/DXSVh.png) to see the image. What Grace Note means by size is the resolution of the image causing the comment threads to be very long, which takes attention away from the Q&A itself. The comment section is meant to be limited...

Comment: @tom Wijsman & Grace note: Would you object to a "expand to see image" line in comments, that when clicked, show the image within the comment?

Comment: @wizlog: Extra text would be unnecessary. Try to ask to change the link to result in [Lightbox2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) functionality, you can try to suggest it at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) which is the network-wide meta...